# ASP / HTML - How to write " character (quote marks) inside ASP code nugget?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I have a line like one below

[image]

The rendered result is:

">Please try again.

The problem is that the produced response goes wrong because it recognize the second quote mark (...[ "asp...) like a closing one for the quote mark before (..."<%: ) , is there any special way to write special chars inside code nuggets ? Tnx in advance

Comment: I don't use asp.net but I would guess \"?

Comment: Tnx , but it does not work

Comment: There shouldn't be any problem in `<a href="<%: Request["aspxerrorpath"]%>">Please try again.</a>` ? What is the exact error you are getting

Comment: the problem is that ASP render href="<%: Request["

Comment: it takes only what between first and second quote marks

Comment: @DimaRudaev, the error is somewhere else. Try `<a href="<%: "SomeURL" %>">Please try again.</a>` and that should work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My preferred option is to change the HTML (well, "ASP.NET Markup") attribute quotes, thus it becomes:

```
<a href='<%: Request["aspxerrorpath"] %>'>Please try again.</a>
```

Even though this uses `'` in the ASP.NET markup it will be rendered as `"` in the page HTML and the `<%:..>` (which doesn't encode `'`) is still guaranteed to render 'valid' HTML.

---

If still "does not work" after changing to the `'` quotes then make sure to view the *actual* HTML returned. With the original quotes it would have resulted in a *parse error* for the entire page (in ASP.NET 3.5 anyway) - and not have returned any related HTML!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
<a href="<%: Request[\"aspxerrorpath\"] %>">Please try again.</a>
```

to write quote inside another qoute use \ before them.

Comment: It will not compile, also `<a href="<%: Request["aspxerrorpath"] %>">Please try again.</a>` should work fine.

Comment: @SoleimanSharifi, yes exactly, so there is no need to escape double quotes

Comment: @Habib That was mistake from me. I correct it :) TY

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Someone offered to try it , and it works , all the credit to the guy who suggested it , I can't see his comment now , Tnx MAN

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple web form showing two ways to get there:

The *.aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="SimpleTestPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.SimpleTestPage" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
      <p>
        Click
        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="GoogleLink">here to get to Google</asp:HyperLink>
        . . .
        or perhaps you'd like to
        <a href="<%=this.AnotherUrl%>">click here to go somewhere else</a>
      </p>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

And its code-behind:

```
using System;

namespace WebApplication1
{
  public partial class SimpleTestPage : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    public string AnotherUrl {  get; set; }

    protected void Page_Load( object sender , EventArgs e )
    {
      this.GoogleLink.NavigateUrl = "http://www.google.com/" ;
      this.AnotherUrl = "http://www.leevalley.com/";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: my code in HTML file , if it was inside a form it was not a problem to get it with code-behind-file , but tnx

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach for me to code double quotes into ASP and C# strings which themselves are "code" is shown below. Use Chr(34) to inject the quote-mark.

This shows how an <a href" string is properly coded in a Response.Write() function, given x.Name is the file name to be accessed with the <a href link:

Response.write("<a href=" & Chr(34) & "http://SheetMusic.links.com/MusicScores/pdf/" & x.Name & Chr(34) & " target=" & Chr(34) & "_blank" & Chr(34) & ">" & x.Name & "
")

This produces filetolink.pdf

Hope this is clear for you.